# Adding items to a JSON encoded array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I am using this solution found on stackoverflow to encode my MYSQL output to a JSON encoded array.

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT ...");

$rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }

print json_encode($rows);
```

This works great and produces an output of

```
[{"id":"81","title":"Something Here","start":"2009-10-27 09:00:00"},{"id":"77","title":"Report on water","start":"2009-10-30 09:00:00"}]
```

Now I need to put a value of say

```
"colour":"Blue"
```

within the JSON encoded array.

So i need the ouput to look like

```
[{"id":"81","title":"Community Awareness","start":"2009-10-27 09:00:00", "colour":"Blue"},{"id":"77","title":"Write a 10,000 Page Report on Emma","start":"2009-10-30 09:00:00", "colour":"Blue"}]
```

Does anyone have any solutions on how I could achieve this?

Thanks,

Tim Mohr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you call json_encode($rows), just edit the value in the $rows array:

```
$rows[0]['colour'] = 'Blue'; // changes the colour of the first row in the array
```

**edit** in fact, if you just want to add a colour to all of the rows, you can do a simple foreach:

```
foreach ($rows as &$row) {
    $row['colour'] = 'Blue';
}
```